Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: only PoS networks are supported, please transition old ones with Geth v1.13.x
Trying to create a Private Ethereum Network Locally, getting above error when tried to start the Node(genesis node)
J:\Aadit\MyNetwork>geth --datadir node1 --networkid 5432 --http --allow-insecure-unlock --nodiscover INFO [06-24|18:58:51.258] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 total=50 INFO [06-24|18:58:51.262] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000 INFO [06-24|18:58:51.262] Initializing the KZG library             backend=gokzg INFO [06-24|18:58:51.272] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB INFO [06-24|18:58:51.274] Using pebble as the backing database INFO [06-24|18:58:51.274] Allocated cache and file handles         database=J:\Aadit\MyNetwork\node1\geth\chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=8192 INFO [06-24|18:58:51.311] Opened ancient database                  database=J:\Aadit\MyNetwork\node1\geth\chaindata\ancient\chain readonly=false INFO [06-24|18:58:51.311] State schema set to default              scheme=path Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: only PoS networks are supported, please transition old ones with Geth v1.13.x 
Will update the solution by installing older version!
